# Convert my xib to arabic language

Tags: ios, localization, xib

My app is going to be made in both English, Arabic languages. I have made my xib using auto layout for english version. Now i want to use same xib for arabic version. But the problem is that interface will also change its layout from right to left.

I know about NSLocalization for xib's but i am clueless for arabic version, I googled last day but not found any thing relevant.

e.g. English version
Icon  label

Arabic version
label Icon

Please put some light in how can i convert my english version of xib to be used in Arabic version.

Thanks

Comment: This document might help you https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/BPInternational/SupportingRight-To-LeftLanguages/SupportingRight-To-LeftLanguages.html

Answer (score 0):

Use [Auto Layout](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AutolayoutPG/Introduction/Introduction.html) in your xibs. By default, the constraints created in Xcode's Interface Builder use Leading/Trailing properties, meaning all of the UI gets automatically flipped in RTL languages.

Like Leszek commented as well, you can check out [Supporting Right-to-Left Languages](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/BPInternational/SupportingRight-To-LeftLanguages/SupportingRight-To-LeftLanguages.html) for anything else.